# Find Index of a Listbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have to find the position of number contained in a Listbox. To find this position I have a target number (called hrrmin in my code) and this Listbox contains numbers that grow with position. I have to find the first number in the Listbox which is greater than the target number. I'm trying this code:

```
Dim lowbound = List.FindIndex(Function(ByVal) hrrmin > Form3.ListBox2.Items)
```

The error I'm having back are multiples:

```
BC30203 - Identifier expected
BC32042 - Too few type arguments to 'List(Of T)'
BC30311 - Value of type 'Listbox' cannot be converted to Double.
```

How could I solve? I have to work with double precision numbers because of precision of decimal numbers.

Comment: `Dim lowbound = List.FindIndex(Function(item) hrrmin > item)`, assuming `List` is the `List(Of Double)` that fills the ListBox. Why are you qualifying the ListBox as `Form3.ListBox2`?

Comment: @Jimi That won't work. `FindIndex()` in an instance method. You can't call it from the type.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn  *assuming `List` is the List(Of Double) that fills the ListBox*. So, an instance. Not clear what's what (and *where*) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListBox` is annoying because the `Items` property only directly implements `IList`... no `IList(Of T)` or `IEnumerable(Of T)`. This means we don't get the normal access to all the nice linq methods without extra work. Usually it's enough that just writing a `For` or `For Each` loop is easier:

```
Dim lowbound As Integer
For lowbound = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count
    If hrrmin < CDbl(ListBox2.Items(i)) Then Exit For
Next index
```

Comment: thanks for tour answer. I have two questions for you: the first is about i in the listbox clause: do I have to set it in another interlaced for loop? The second one comes because of my fault, because I didn't write it: from all of indexes for hrrmin greater than listbox items, how could I get easely the first? In other words i have to know the position of the first listbox item smaller than hrrmin

Answer (score 0):

Just a little update on the answer provided by @Joel Coehoorn.

```
    Dim lowbound As Integer 'The index of the first item that meets criteria
    Dim hrrmin = 4
    For lowbound = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If hrrmin < CInt(ListBox1.Items(lowbound)) Then Exit For
    Next
    Debug.Print(lowbound.ToString)
```